# Custom JsonConverter for nested Dictionary<,> Json.Net

Tags: serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have an issue with Json deserialization of my dictionary.
I have the following data structure:

```
public class GameObject
 {
  public GameObject()
  {
     Components = new Dictionary<UInt64, List<EntityComponent>>();
  }

  public Entity EntityTree { get; set; }

  public Dictionary<UInt64, List<EntityComponent>> Components { get; set; }
}
```

I tried it with String as Key, but it return exception which says that It cannot convert value of the dictionary (its madness).
Could someone help me to write correct reader/writer for this structure that could deserialize my dictionary correctly?
I cannot understand the way how to do it correctly.

Please, help me!

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: My JSON is like this:
"Components": {
    "$id": "5",
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.UInt64, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[EntityComponentSystem.ECS.Components.EntityComponent, 3DObjectsConverter]], mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "3": [
      {
        "$id": "6",
        "$type": "ObjectsConverter.Components.RawGeometryComponent, 3DObjectsConverter",
        "Indices": [